# Read the content of a child of a child with javascript

Tags: javascript, children

i'd like to create a function that gets prices as dynamic content and calculates an installment payment. I tried several approaches but they do not work. Unfortunately i don't get an error msg.

Maybe you could help my drenched brain a bit. Thank you a lot in advance

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('article-price')[0];
   var secondwrapper = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
   var price = secondwrapper.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
   
   var installment = document.getElementById('installment');
   installment.innerHTML = (price.innerHTML / 12).toFixed(2);
```

```html
<span class="article-price">
 <span>
  <span>149,99</span>
    <span>€</span>
 </span>
</span>
<div>your installment is <span id="installment"></span></div>
```

Comment: Dividing a string by a number `'150'/12` will return `75` as a number because '150' can be converted to 150. (_It still is bad practice to mix types_.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `var price = secondwrapper.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];` by `var price = parseFloat(secondwrapper.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML.replace(',','.'));` to get the content of your span and replace comma by point to get the string as float number. 
If you don't replace replace the comma by a point, JavaScript won't understand that '149,99' is a number and will only keep '149' because `,` is not recognized as decimal separator, while `.` is.
`getElementsByTagName` will give you the whole tag and not only the value inside as you wanted. Then in last line, remove `price.innerHTML` to `price` because you already converted it earlier.

Here's a snippet to help you

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('article-price')[0];
var secondwrapper = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
var price = parseFloat(secondwrapper.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML.replace(',','.'));
var installment = document.getElementById('installment');
installment.innerHTML = parseFloat(price / 12).toFixed(2) + " €";
```

```html
<span class="article-price">
    <span>
        <span>149,99</span>
        <span>€</span>
    </span>
</span>
<div>your installment is <span id="installment"></span></div>
```

I hope my answer helped you !

Comment: Works flawless! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('article-price')[0];
   var secondwrapper = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
   var price = secondwrapper.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];

   var installment = document.getElementById('installment');
   installment.innerHTML = (parseFloat(price.innerHTML) / 12).toFixed(2);
```

```
<span class="article-price">
    <span>
        <span>149,99</span>
    <span>€</span>
    </span>
</span>
<div>your installment is <span id="installment"></span></div>
```

Could it be the comma inside the span throwing things out. Not sure if it will work but you could try parseFloat, which should read it as a number or parseInt;

Comment: `'149,99'` gets parsed as `149` and is missing the `.99`. When you are parsing strings which use a comma as the decimal seperator you have to replace it first: `parseFloat(price.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '.')) / 12`

Comment: Good to know, not sure of the etiquette should I steal your code and edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to change last line of code only:

```
installment.innerHTML = (parseFloat(price.innerHTML.replace(/\,/g,"")) / 12).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: What's the need for the ````.replace(/\,/g,"")```` out of interest, won't parseFloat remove most extra characters,

Comment: The replace is wrong if the comma is meant to be the decimal seperator. This will parse `149,99` as `14999` which is (probably) way too much.

Comment: if comma is not replaced with empty then parseFlot will take first part of string as only 149 out of 149,99. That's why replace is used.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code it might help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('article-price');
  alert(wrapper);
  var secondwrapper = wrapper[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
  alert(secondwrapper.innerHTML);
  var price = secondwrapper.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
  alert(price.innerHTML);
  var installment = document.getElementById('installment');
 installment.innerHTML = (parseFloat(price.innerHTML) / 12).toFixed(2);
});
```

instead of wrapper you have to use wrapper[0] which will point to zeroth position of the span and moreover you have to change the text to float

```
installment.innerHTML = (parseFloat(price.innerHTML) / 12).toFixed(2);
```